# Passing arguments to different controllers on "itemClick" event of list items in list view in appcelerator

Tags: controller, arguments, parameter-passing, appcelerator-titanium

I need to pass url, title and date of the clicked item in listview from DashboardController to VideoPlayerController. The url that i will be passing to VideoPlayerController should make the video autoplay. how do i proceed here?

This is the code for DashboardController.js

```
var args = $.args;

var sections = [];
//JSON to populate the listview
var videoInfo = [{
    pic : "/Images/playButton.png",
    info : "This in the the title for the first video.",
    date : "03/07/2017",
    url : "https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9khttps://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"
}, {
    pic : "/Images/playButton.png",
    info : "This in the the title for the second video.",
    date : "03/07/2017",
    url : "https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9khttps://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"
}, {
    pic : "/Images/playButton.png",
    info : "This in the the title for the third video.",
    date : "03/07/2017",
    url : "https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9khttps://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"
}];

function populateListView() {
    Ti.API.trace("[DashboardController.js  >>  populateListView() >>]");
    if (!_.isEmpty(videoInfo)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < videoInfo.length; i++) {
            var item = {
                template : "videoTemplate",
                iconId : {
                    image : videoInfo[i].pic
                },
                titleId : {
                    text : videoInfo[i].info
                },
                dateId : {
                    text : videoInfo[i].date
                },
                urlId : {
                    text : videoInfo[i].url
                },
                properties : {
                    backgroundColor : "transparent"
                }
            };
            sections.push(item);
        }
       $.listSection.setItems(sections);
    }
}  
populateListView();
$.lView.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var dataItem = $.listSection.get(e.itemIndex) ;
    var videoController = Alloy.createController('VideoPlayerController',{
    "url":$.url,
    "title":$.info,
    "date":$.date
    }).getView();
});
```

This is the code for Dashboard Controller.xml

```
    <Alloy>
        <View id="win2" class="container">
            <View id = "v1" class ="view1"  layout ="horizontal" >
                <Button class="btnBack" ></Button>
                <Label  class = "label1">LIST VIEW EXAMPLE</Label>
            </View>
            <View class="view2">
                <TextField id = "txtSearch"></TextField>
            </View>
            <ListView id = "lView" class = "list1" >
                 <Templates>
                        <ItemTemplate name="videoTemplate">
                            <View class = "viewTemplate" layout = "horizontal" >
                                <ImageView bindId="iconId"  id="pic"  />
                                <View class = "viewTitle" layout = "vertical" >
                                    <Label bindId="titleId" id="info" />
                                    <View class="viewDtUrl" layout="horizontal" >
                                        <Label bindId="dateId" id="date" />
                                        <Label bindId="urlId" id ="url" /> 
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                </Templates>
                <ListSection id = "listSection">
                </ListSection>
            </ListView>   
        </View>
    </Alloy> 

And this is the code for VideoPlayerController.xml

<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <VideoPlayer class = "video"></VideoPlayer>
        <View class="videoInfoView" layout="vetical" backgroundColor="blue">
            <Label class="titleInfo"></Label>
            <View class = "infoLabel" layout="horizontal" backgroundColor="yellow">
                <Label class="dateInfo"></Label>
                <Label class="urlInfo"></Label>
            </View>>
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```